# Make rows equal in height as per screen height in Android device

Tags: android, row

I have three rows and in that I want to fix these rows size equal and it will be based upon the size of screen which we are giving to this table as whole,means it will divide three rows equally as per given height,same is done for column by using `android:stretchColumns="0,1"`.
Tabel structure is attached below:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/tabelViewButtons"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/searchbar" android:layout_above="@id/follow_notification_bar"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:stretchColumns="0,1"
        >
    <TableRow >
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_one"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_two"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow >
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_three"></ImageButton>

        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_four"></ImageButton>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow >
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_five"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:padding="5dip"
            android:id="@+id/button_six"></ImageButton>

    </TableRow>
    >

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

set the attribute `android:layout_weight="1"` for each `TableRow`

Comment: Thanks, debugging code for the reasons. But you're suggestion worked perfectly.